# How to check if another directive is present on the same element

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive

Suppose I have two directives:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDirective1]'
})
export class Directive1Directive {

  public alone = true;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.alone) {
      this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = "I am alone";
    } else {
      this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = "I have a friend";
    }
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDirective2]'
})
export class Directive2Directive {

  constructor() { }

}
```

I want `Directive1` to change its behavior if `Directive2` is present on the same element. For example, these should have different behavior.

```
<div appDirective1></div>
<div appDirective1 appDirective2></div>
```

Is it possible for me to do this without adding a service to facilitate communication*?

StackBlitz Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgqd15

---

*I would like to avoid creating a new service for this because that feels like overkill.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can inject the neighboring directives via the constructor using a [Host()](https://angular.io/api/core/Host) decorator, and also make it [Optional()](https://angular.io/api/core/Optional)

```js
  constructor(@Optional() @Host() public friend: Directive2Directive) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.friend) {
      this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = "I have a friend";
    } else {
      this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = "I am alone";
    }
  }
```

Components, directives and providers are injectable and you can limit DI to only search on the current *host* level.

Comment: Is there a reason you'd prefer `@Host` over `@Self` (https://angular.io/api/core/Self)? I'm not super familiar with the difference, but my initial impression is that `@Host` will cast a wider net

Comment: @Vlad274 `@Self()` starts at the current host and walks upwards until it finds the provider. `@Host()` only looks at the current host and stops if it is not found.

Comment: Wow, so `@Self` is actually the wider net! Thanks for the information!

Comment: @Vlad274 I have a feeling that `@Self()` is the default, because we also have `@SkipSelf()` so what is the difference when you don't use `@Self()`? So that's why I think it's the default, but I checked the docs and can't confirm it there.

Answer (score 2):

I consider [Reactgular's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57312807/3980115) to be superior because it can be easily be applied to either directive as required.

---

Depending on the relationship between the two directives, I have found the following solutions:

### Let `Directive1` explicitly check for `Directive2`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDirective1]'
})
export class Directive1Directive {

  public alone = true;

  @Input("appDirective2")
  public appDirective2: any;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.appDirective2 !== undefined) {
      this.alone = false;
    }
    if (this.alone) {
      this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = "I am alone";
    } else {
      this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = "I have a friend";
    }
  }
}
```

StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5w63vu

### Provide a hook for `Directive2` to tell `Directive1`:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDirective1]'
})
export class Directive1Directive {

  public alone = true;

  constructor(private element: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setContent();
  }

  setFriend() {
    this.alone = false;
    this.setContent();
  }

  setContent() {
    if (this.alone) {
      this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = "I am alone";
    } else {
      this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = "I have a friend";
    }
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDirective2]'
})
export class Directive2Directive {

  constructor(@Self() private otherDirective: Directive1Directive ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.otherDirective.setFriend();
  }
}
```

StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bag8wa